# How do I create a search similar to the browser 'find'?

Tags: javascript, php, search, find, instant

I'm looking for some advice/help, I have a page which lists 100's of SKU's and I need to create a search where you enter the stockcode and it will take you to that specific section of the page.

In a nutshell it will work like the browser 'find'.

This must be done with out the page reloading...

Again the question is: How do I create a search similar to the browser 'find'?

Comment: Thanks for the comment Arnaud, I've just taken a look at the link provided and the Fiddler URL use as a demo doesn't work when you search... have you used this before? does it work?

Comment: The [second provided JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ryleyb/VFVZL/1/) based on the same plugin seems to work